# Load separate jFrame in jInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktop

I am new to Java desktop app. I have built `JDesktopPane` with two buttons.

In that button click it will load two separate `JInternalFrames`.

I have already developed two separate `JFrame` classes (which denotes two modules). So I want to know, Can I load those `JFrame` in those `JInternalFrames` ?

Comment: I dont think you can add JFrame inside a JInternalFrame, instead you can change your classes to be JPanel and use it inside JInternalFrame.

Comment: @HarryJoy Make this an answer

Comment: @HarryJoy You are absolutely right, anything descending from `Window` can not be added to another container.  Please make it answer so I can up-vote it! +1 to the comment

Comment: @tmwanik thanks for the suggestion, but this one line doesn't worth to be answer. It just simple information, so let it be in comment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for appreciation but look at my previous comment, it is not an answer.

Comment: @HarryJoy "No" is also the answer, as simple as it is, your answer is correct

Comment: @Harry Thanks. I done this by implementing jFrame under jPanel